# CRM 4.0 Business Unit Entity, cannot create N:1/N:N Relationship

Tags: many-to-many, dynamics-crm, entity-relationship, dynamics-crm-4, many-to-one

As title,

I'm trying to create a N:1 (businessunit : custom_entity) relationship in CRM 4.0

The `New Many-to-One Relationship` button option is missing from the UI

I could create N:1 relationship for other entities, but just not for `businessunit`

Is this a well known limitation in CRM 4.0?

Or do I have something mis-configured in the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the built in entities have certain types of relationships disabled or creation of new fields disabled. Business Unit is one of those, so you're not doing anything wrong, you've just hit a limitation of CRM.